# Can not start redis-clutser in using kubernetes

Tags: docker, kubernetes, operating-system

Using this command `helm install wd-redis-cluster bitnami/redis-cluster`,
I tried to start up a k8s redis-cluster locally on Mac with m1 chip, but get the following output.

```
NAME                                              READY   STATUS             RESTARTS          AGE

wd-redis-cluster-0                                0/1     CrashLoopBackOff   10 (2m52s ago)    25m
wd-redis-cluster-1                                0/1     CrashLoopBackOff   9 (3m12s ago)     25m
wd-redis-cluster-2                                0/1     CrashLoopBackOff   9 (3m17s ago)     25m
wd-redis-cluster-3                                0/1     CrashLoopBackOff   9 (3m2s ago)      25m
wd-redis-cluster-4                                0/1     CrashLoopBackOff   9 (2m51s ago)     25m
wd-redis-cluster-5                                0/1     CrashLoopBackOff   10 (2m32s ago)    25m
```

Logs are as follows

```
$ kubectl logs wd-redis-cluster-5 

redis-cluster 10:57:31.18 
redis-cluster 10:57:31.57 Welcome to the Bitnami redis-cluster container
redis-cluster 10:57:32.15 Subscribe to project updates by watching https://github.com/bitnami/bitnami-docker-redis-cluster
redis-cluster 10:57:32.68 Submit issues and feature requests at https://github.com/bitnami/bitnami-docker-redis-cluster/issues
redis-cluster 10:57:33.48 
redis-cluster 10:57:35.03 INFO  ==> ** Starting Redis setup **
redis-cluster 10:57:40.95 INFO  ==> Initializing Redis
redis-cluster 10:57:42.97 INFO  ==> Setting Redis config file
Changing old IP 172.17.0.14 by the new one 172.17.0.14
/bin/sed: can't read /bitnami/redis/data/nodes.conf: No such file or directory
```

Anyone can help?

Comment: Does file /bitnami/redis/data/nodes.conf exist?

Comment: Check [this github issue](https://github.com/bitnami/charts/issues/2937) - it looks the same to what you have and probably related to `storageClass` setup. Let me know if this helps

Comment: @fireman777 can not `exec` into the pod.

Comment: What is the default `storageClass`? What does it have in `volumeBindingMode`?